# Why is my table not respecting my fixed COL width?

Tags: html, css, tablelayout, fixed-width

I have this table:  http://jsfiddle.net/fere_tzau/7pwn48zf/  .
What I want to resolve is : keep a `table-layout: fixed` property but add a fixed value to the first col `<col width="100">` .

If I add a fixed value to the `<col>` this will have some sort of percent width.(Calendar blocks courses should always have a fixed width, lets say 150px ).

But by using the `table-layout:auto` the fixed width works. ( but my table looks messed up ).

> I want the first `<col>` to be fixed in width.

Maybe this answer is already here but I cant find it, maybe what I want is not even possible.

Thanks.

Comment: The code looks quite messy. why do you want to keep so many `<col>` tags?

Comment: Ignore the cols , those will be generated from js (the timeline will be dynamic ) Maybe we will show 2 years, and we need to show the courses span ( eg 5 mar > 18 Jun )...

Comment: Still unable to get your question clear. As I understand, you are trying to make a graphical interface kind of table which will depict a timeline of something around the year. Please elaborate your question.

Comment: >>> What I want to resolve is : keep a table-layout: fixed property but add a fixed value to the first col <col width="100"> <<< Is this not clear enough ?  I need a fixed <COL> but the table property "fixed" :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tr > :first-child {width:100px;}` to select only the first column cells and apply a width or other attribute.